# How to find address of last used cell in row for use in formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a row of values in a range and need to subtract the value in the last cell in the row from the value of the first cell of the row. The challenge is that the last cell location is unknown, so the formula needs to be general.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please take a minute to read through the [Help Center](http://superuser.com/help) to learn how this site works and how to improve your question with details of what you have researched and attempted to resolve this issue on your own.

Answer (score 2):

This formula finds the **last** number in the range A2:Z2, adjust as required:

`=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A2:Z2)`

`9.99E+307` is [almost] the largest number that excel can handle, when the lookup value is so large that it won't be found in the range then that results in the formula finding the **last** number in that range